# How to 'insert' a new page inside a TPageControl

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

Best way to 'insert' a page in a TPageControl if i already have many pages full of controls? Let's say i want to insert a new page before TabSheet1.

Thanks.

UPDATE : At design time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try this

```
procedure TForm13.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
Var
   tabSheet: TTabSheet;
   AComponent: TComponent;
   aIndex: Integer;
begin
   aIndex:=-1;

   AComponent := FindComponent('TabSheet1');
   if Assigned(AComponent) then
     if AComponent is TTabSheet then
       aIndex := TTabSheet(AComponent).PageIndex; //get the index of the 'TabSheet1'  

   tabSheet := TTabSheet.Create(PageControl1);
   tabSheet.PageControl := PageControl1;
   tabSheet.Caption := 'My TabSheet'+IntToStr(PageControl1.PageCount);
   if aIndex>-1 then
     tabSheet.PageIndex := aIndex; //Set the index of the new TabSheet
end;
```

**Update**

In Designtime you must set the PageIndex Property to the PageIndex of the TabSheet1.

Bye.

Comment: There's a lot of code in that example. The part that actually *answers the question* is the last line, where `PageIndex` gets assigned a new value.

Comment: I should have said inserting at design time. (May be i should edit my question?)

Comment: That's what i thought. OK - thank for the code anyway it will be usefull.

Comment: I'd vote this answer up if it wasn't a textbook example on how to (mis-)use indentation and white space to make code less readable.

Comment: So fix it, Mghie. It's a wiki.

Answer (score 13):

**Rightclick** on the pagecontrol, and click <kbd>New Page</kbd>

After that, set the `PageIndex` property to place the new page where you want to have it.